# How to understand that the orientation of midpoint velocity is same as the bar's in terms of its constraint equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I am learning non-holonomic constraints with a book, in which an example tells that the velocity of the midpoint of a bar is directed in bar's direction as it is shown by the constraint equation

$$\frac{\dot{y_1}+\dot{y_2}}{y_2-y_1} = \frac{\dot{x_1}+\dot{x_2}}{x_2-x_1}$$

What I don't understand is the derivation of this equation. Does this mean that the ratio of velocity components
$$\frac{\dot{v_y}}{\dot{v_x}}$$
is equal to the slope
$$k= tan(\theta)=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello,  @Farcher.  I saw your answers in other questions are quite expertised. Any opinion for my question is appreciated.

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic   Thanks for reply. The book is quite old and I have only few pages of this. The description in the book is almost the same as what I posted here. Two particles connected with a rigid bar or line. Then it gives the constraint equation as the one in my post. What I am not sure is how it is derived.